# Update a JSF 2.2 Form with Primefaces - ViewstateMissing

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

i upgraded to jsf 2.2 and primefaces 3.5 (can't find 3.5.7 in maven repo)

i have some pages where a form-element is updated

```
<h:form id="myform">
         <p:commandButton update="myform" />
</h:form>
```

this reanders on the first load to

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/Brainyoo2/pages/test.html?conversationContext=2" method="post" name="myform" id="myform">
    <input type="hidden" value="myform" name="myform">
    <button type="submit" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'myform:j_idt33',update:'myform'});return false;" class="" name="myform:j_idt33" id="myform:j_idt33" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
        <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">ui-button</span>
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="2334157823875715239:-6429653122802219998" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" name="javax.faces.ViewState">
</form>
```

after clicking the button it renders per ajax to

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/Brainyoo2/pages/test.html?conversationContext=2" method="post" name="myform" id="myform">
    <input type="hidden" value="myform" name="myform">
    <button type="submit" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'myform:j_idt33',update:'myform'});return false;" class="" name="myform:j_idt33" id="myform:j_idt33" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
        <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">ui-button</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

means the ViewState is missing, and is not send in furter requests. When i realize this example with a

```
<h:commandButton and <f:ajax
```

it works.

i already tried '4.0-SNAPSHOT' but it has the same problem

any ideas how to fix it without changing every html page?

Comment: I don't think Primefaces provides support for JSF2.2 just yet

Answer (score 0):

Do you try with `@form` in **update**?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @FranzKafka - although you're right it should be noted that he cannot comment yet because of rep points.

Comment: I don´t wanna be annoying anybody I just wanna help to @wutzebaer but if annoying can delete the answer.

Comment: I think problem are JSF 2.2 downgraded to 2.1 or 2.0 (how say @kolossus) and I´m sure that be work. And you can´t download 3.5.7 primefaces because the latest version a pf free are 3.5.

Comment: hm ok in another project jsf 2.2 and primefaces 3.5 work well together, so my next assumption is that the problem occurs with the combination of primefaces + jsf-2.2 + myfaces-orchestra-1.5

Comment: can you write **ui:composition**?